# document.title element disappears on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gridsome

I am trying to get the page title with this. It works fine opening the page the first time but on refresh it disappears.

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <section id="courses">
        <p>{{ pageTitle }}</p>
    </section>
  </Layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageTitle: document.title
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I also tried to do it with 'created, mounted...' etc. I couldn't get it to work.
What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Vue Router?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am using Gridsome, I think it uses vue-router?

Comment: Is this the default route or a different one?

Comment: Different one. Another page. https://gridsome.org/docs/pages/ 
I am using "File-based pages"

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I know enough about Gridsome to help you

Comment: N.p. Do you think this is a gridsome problem.

Comment: How are you setting the page title?

Comment: Is it happening only for `document` properties or for other things too?